# django request.POST is None

Tags: django

This is views.py

```
class RegisterView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        register_form = RegisterForm()
        return render(request,'register.html',{'register_form':register_form})

    def post(self,request):
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            pass

class LoginView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request,'login.html',{})
    def post(self,request):
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user_name = request.POST.get("username", '')
            pass_word = request.POST.get("password", '')
            user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'index.html') 
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html', {"msg": "User name or password error!"})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'login':login_form})
```

Why does register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST) and login_form = LoginForm(request.POST) return empty,I tried many ways to solve it but failed, so how should I write it?

this is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True) 
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=5)  

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True,min_length=5)
    captcha = CaptchaField(error_messages={"invalid":'captcha is error'})
```

this is login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="renderer" content="webkit">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" >
 <title>mxonline</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="dialog" id="jsDialog">

<div class="successbox dialogbox" id="jsSuccessTips">
    <h1>successful</h1>
    <div class="close jsCloseDialog"><img src="/static/images/dig_close.png"/></div>
    <div class="cont">
        <h2>submit successful！</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="noactivebox dialogbox" id="jsUnactiveForm" >
    <h1>Email verification prompt</h1>
    <div class="close jsCloseDialog"><img src="/static/images/dig_close.png"/></div>
    <div class="center">
        <img src="/static/images/send.png"/>
        <p>We have already sent your email to you<span class="green" id="jsEmailToActive">12@13.com</span>Send email, <br/> to ensure your account security, please check email in time</p>
        <p class="a"><a class="btn" id="jsGoToEmail" target="_blank" href="http://mail.qq.com">Check the mailbox</a></p>
        <p class="zy_success upmove"></p>
        <p style="display: none;" class="sendE2">You can check your spam and the filtered message, and you can send it again（<span class="c5c">60s</span>）</p>
        <p class="sendE">You can check your spam and filtered emails，<br/>Can also be<span class="c5c green" id="jsSenEmailAgin" style="cursor: pointer;">Send the validation email again</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bg" id="dialogBg"></div>
<header>
    <div class="c-box fff-box">
        <div class="wp header-box">
            <p class="fl hd-tips">mxonlie</p>
            <ul class="fr hd-bar">
                <li>tel：<span>33333333</span></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="login.html">[login]</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.html">[registration]</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="c-box bg-box">
        <div class="login-box clearfix">
            <div class="hd-login clearfix">
                <a class="index-logo" href="index.html"></a>
                <h1>login</h1>
                <a class="index-font" href="index.html">index</a>
            </div>
            <div class="fl slide">
                <div class="imgslide">
                    <ul class="imgs">
                            <li><a href=""><img width="483" height="472" src="/static/images/mysql.jpg" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img width="483" height="472" src="/static/images/mysql.jpg" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><img width="483" height="472" src="/static/images/mysql.jpg" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="unslider-arrow prev"></div>
                <div class="unslider-arrow next"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fl form-box">
                <h2>login</h2>
                <form action="/login/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='mymQDzHWl2REXIfPMg2mJaLqDfaS1sD5' />
                    <div class="form-group marb20 {% if login_form.errors.username %}errorput{% endif %}">
                        <label>&nbsp;username&nbsp</label>
                        <input name="username" id="account_l" type="text" placeholder="Mobile phone number/mailbox" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group marb8 {% if login_form.errors.username %}errorput{% endif %}">
                        <label>password</label>
                        <input name="password" id="password_l" type="password" placeholder="Please enter your password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="error btns login-form-tips" id="jsLoginTips">{% for key,error in login_form.errors.items %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}{{ msg }}</div>
                     <div class="auto-box marb38">

                        <a class="fr" href="forgetpwd.html">Forget password？</a>
                     </div>
                     <input class="btn btn-green" id="jsLoginBtn" type="submit" value="Login immediately > " />
{#                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='5I2SlleZJOMUX9QbwYLUIAOshdrdpRcy' />#}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
                <p class="form-p">No online account？<a href="register.html">[Register now]</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/unslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/login.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The question of register_form = RegisterForm (request.post) has been resolved, but login_form = login_form = LoginForm (request.post) is still empty,so I just uploaded login.html

Comment: We probably need to see the register.html template and the RegisterForm class to see what is going on.

Comment: Please include the definitions of your forms.

Comment: Why have you shown index.html? It's the template containing the form, register.html, that we need to see.

Comment: In the LoginView, you never pass on the LoginForm in the GET request. Yet some sort of form appears to show up in the html which confuses me. Did you type all that html yourself or are you using {{ form }} in your templates? If not why not?